# Proof of Marcinkiewicz-Zygmund strong law of large numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, law-of-large-numbers

Marcinkiewicz-Zygmund strong law of large numbers:

> Let $X_1,X_2,···$ be i.i.d. with $E|X_1|^p< \infty$ for some $0< p <2$. Then
> $$
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{S_n - nEX}{n^{1/p}} \to 0 \text{ a.s.} & \text{if } 1< p < 2\\
> \frac{S_n}{n^{1/p}} \to 0 \text{ a.s.} & \text{if } 0<p<1\\
> \end{cases}
> $$ where $S_n = X_1+X_2+\cdots +X_n$.

I tried to use Kronecker’s lemma, so we just need to show
$$
\begin{cases}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{X_n-EX}{n^{1/p}} \text{ converges a.s.} & \text{if } 1< p < 2\\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{X_n}{n^{1/p}} \text{ converges a.s.} & \text{if } 0<p<1\\
\end{cases}
$$
Moreover, by Kolmogorov Three Series Theorem,  it is equivalent to show
$$
\begin{cases}
\sum_n P(|X_n|>n^{1/p})<\infty \\
\sum_n E\left(\frac{X_n}{n^{1/p}} 1_{\{|X_n|<n^{1/p}\}} \right)\text{ converges} \\
\sum_n \text{Var}\left(\frac{X_n}{n^{1/p}} 1_{\{|X_n|<n^{1/p}\}} \right)<\infty
\end{cases}
$$
For the first one, I can use $E|X_n|^p< \infty$ to prove, but for the rest two I have no idea how to bound them.

Comment: There is a  difference between $\sum a_n <\infty$ and $\sum a_n$ convergent.

Comment: Oh, I even don't realise this, I have updated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint for the case $1<p<2$. Assume that $X_1$ is centered.
Since $X_n$ has the same distribution as $X_1$, we have
$$
\mathbb E\left(\frac{X_n}{n^{1/p}} 1_{\{|X_n|<n^{1/p}\}} \right)=\mathbb E\left(\frac{X_1}{n^{1/p}} 1_{\{|X_1|<n^{1/p}\}} \right).
$$
Since $X_1$ is centered, we have
$$
\mathbb E\left(\frac{X_1}{n^{1/p}} 1_{\{|X_1|<n^{1/p}\}} \right)=\mathbb E\left(\frac{X_1}{n^{1/p}} 1_{\{|X_1|\geqslant n^{1/p}\}} \right).
$$
then use the same type of argument that are used to show the convergence of the first series.